# Unable to store and access Session Variables in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to store session simply by doing `session[:user_id] = 1`. When I access it in next line by doing `puts(session)` it prints `<ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection::ProtectionMethods::NullSession::NullSessionHash:0x0000010433dda8>`

I m also not able to fetch `session[:user_id]` in other pages.

Comment: `RequestForgeryProtection::ProtectionMethods` This is not allowing session to get stored try adding `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` this line in `SessionsController`

Comment: @Sontya  I am not using devise. Should I add it then every controller?

Comment: oh I was not knowing that, then that will not be a good idea to add to every controller. Try changing changing you store type, bydefault session uses `CookieStore` change it to `CacheStore` in your development.rb file       `YourAppName::Application.configure do
  config.session_store = ActionDispatch::Sessions::CacheStore
end`

Answer (score 1):

You are using [NullStore](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-nullstore). Just configure other store (file, memcached, etc.)